# Getting OpenCL to work on Linux laptop with Optimus technology

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencl

I have an installation of Kubuntu 13.10 on my laptop which has an Nvidia GT555m with optimus technology. I am having some trouble getting my C++ code with OpenCL to compile.

The error I keep getting is `Cannot find -lOpenCL`. Doing a quick search with the GNU find utility gives me the following:

```
/usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-319/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

I have the following OpenCL development packages installed:

```
opencl-headers
nvidia-opencl-dev
```

I also tried the utility `clinfo` to see if I get any information, but I get the following error:

```
clinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any experience setting up a Linux development environment with OpenCL on their optimus laptops?

I was under the impression that I do not need to do anything fancy to get this working.

**EDIT**: Ok it seems the reason I was not managing to compile was because I was mixing up headers and libraries. Using the following compiles my code well:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/cuda-5.5/include vadd.cpp -L /usr/lib/nvidia-331 -lOpenCL
```

I am getting another error during runtime now (but at least I managed to compile!). The error is as follows:

```
ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs
-1001
```

From doing some research this means I probably do not have the ICD portion of nvidias toolkit installed? What I cannot understand is - where to find it!

Comment: Did you try to add path to link dirs with:  `-L/usr/lib32/nvidia-319/` ?

Comment: Ye I did that and it kind of work, but its not compiling well. What I cant understand is which version of the library I should choose. The libopencl-dev package I installed placed the libOpenCL.so file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and the appropriate headers in /usr/include. However, If I try add it to my library path it just complains it cant find lOpenCL! The one in the nvidia-319 path just does not seem to want to compile for me as soon as I add some basic commands, but at least it doesn't complain that it cant find lOpenCL :/

Answer (score 1):

You should install the [Nvidia Cuda SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). It contains *OpenCL* development libraries and includes.

Comment: I Installed cuda 5.0 and associated development pacakges from my package manager (its what advised by most Ubuntu users). However I still get the same error (cannot find -lOpenCL)

Comment: @MichaelAquilina I didn't know the ubuntu package.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need development packages or libraries, (OpenCL is already there, and working, just giving you a runtime error, ICD is present). What you need is a platform ready to execute the OpenCL code, so a GPU + a driver.

You need to install the propietary driver of nVIDIA: Either by using the Ubuntu tools, or by installing the package `nvidia-current`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to install [bublebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html). A library to use Cuda on Nvidia cards with optimus technology.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Kubuntu yet I got it working under Mageia release 6 Linux so I guess it should be pretty similar. In my case there were Intel and Nvidia (GeForce GTX 980M) graphic cards together in my laptop. My intention was to get running only OpenCL compiled code without any set up of Xorg graphical server.

So, as advised above by DarkZeros I did it by using only a proprietary nvidia driver (in my case downloaded from Nvidia page). Then under root user:

```
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run --no-opengl-files
```

It asked me if I wanted to modify my Xorg configuration - I said "NO". This delivered nvidia kernel modules. Next, I modified /etc/modules to let the Linux know that it should load them at start up of system (this might be different on Kubuntu)

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/modules
nvidia
nvidia-uvm 
nvidia-drm
nvidia-modeset
```

and that was really it. Reboot your system and loading of modules should automatically also create correct nvidia device files under a /dev directory.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /dev/nvidia*
/dev/nvidia0  /dev/nvidiactl  /dev/nvidia-uvm  /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
```

I've got an inspiration from [ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/295.59/README/optimus.html][1]